# Multi-page form without registration using sessions

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to allow the user to post data to my server as part of a multi-page form without requiring registration. This form post includes a file upload. I'd rather not use ajax for the whole form if I can help it.

This raises the issue of what happens if the user abandons the form mid-way through.

I am new to php but I was wondering if the following is sensible:

Page 1: On "submit", store infromation in session
Page 2: On "submit" store page one and page two data in database.

That way I can have multipage forms but the information is only loaded to my database when the user completes the second page.

Would something like this work?

Comment: Developers do this all of the time. Of course you would have to handle the file upload when the form is finally submitted.

Comment: @JayBlanchard What about if I uploaded it to a temp directory and then made it copy the file to the real directory when the user submits, is that possible

Comment: That is the way that PHP normally does things @JamesWillson. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php